# Triggering textfield via Table View did select iOS - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

In an iOS apps I have a table view that has 2 rows with textfield embedded inside.
[image]

Textfield2 is a textfield with pickerview input that I set with something like this:

`textField2.inputView = pickerView;`

So the thing is , the textField 2 icon on the right is only an image embedded in the textfield2.rightview that caused the image to not trigger the pickerView input when tapped.

Did select table view method also wasn't triggered because I set the textfield to fully occupy the cell. Thus, after some searching I find that disabling the textField2 user interaction enabling the didSelect to be triggered.

`textField2.userInteractionEnabled = false;`

However, now I'm at lost on to how to trigger the input to textField2 pickerView via the didselect tableview method. I tried this line of code but that doesn't work.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Did select row %d",indexPath.row);
    if(indexPath.row == 1){
        [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

I tried to search how to trigger input manually to textField and didn't find any clue.
Thanks before ! :)

Comment: The textfield should come from the cell, something like ```cell.textField2.becomeFirstResponer```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging with a clear mind, I find that

```
textField2.userInteractionEnabled = false;
```

caused the textfield not able be the responder.
So a little workaround with this flag is enable it first in order to edit the text field and disable it again after we finished editing. Something like this :

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Did select row %d",indexPath.row);
    if(indexPath.row == 1){

        [textField2.userInteractionEnabled = true;
        [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}

- (void)donePicker {
// to enable the did select row again
        [textField2.userInteractionEnabled = true;
}
```